# Let $G= \langle a \rangle$ be a cyclic group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. Show $(G/H,*)$ is a cyclic group with generator $aH$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G=\langle a \rangle$ be a cyclic group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. Show $(G/H,*)$ is a cyclic group with generator $aH$. Also find a group $K$ with normal subgroup $L$ such that $(K/L,*)$ is abelian, but $K$ is not abelian.

---

We can accept:

*Lemma:* Let $G$ be a group, $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$. Let $b \in G$, then $(bH)^n=b^nH$, $\forall n\in \Bbb{Z}$ .

---

So, I need help figuring this out. What I have so far is this:

Since $G$ is cyclic then it is abelian and we get the result that $H$ is a normal subgroup. From here let $G=\langle a \rangle=\{a,a^2,\cdots,a^m,e\}$. If we write out all the left cosets for $H$ in $G$ we have $gH=\{aH,a^2H,\cdots,a^mH,H\}$, $g\in G$. From here we can easily see that$$\langle aH \rangle=\{(aH)^1,(aH)^2,\cdots,(aH)^m,(H)^{m+1}\}=\{aH,a^2H,\cdots,a^mH,H\}.$$

Is this logically correct? And any hints on the second part of the question?

Comment: Hint for non-abelian group with abelian quotient:  what is the smallest non-abelian group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is pretty sound.

$G/H$ is the homomorphic image of $G$ via the canonical projection map $\pi$, with $\pi (a)=aH$.  (In general,  the homomorphic image of a cyclic group is cyclic, generated by the image of a generator.)

For part $2$, consider $K=S_3$ and $L=\{(123), (132),e\}$.

Or, try to find any nonabelian  group that does not equal its commutator subgroup. (Like $S_n$ and $A_n$.)  This is because the commutator is the smallest normal subgroup for which the quotient is abelian.  (Try the quaternions, or $A_4$, for instance.  The latter has commutator the Klein four group.  The former also works.  So these provide examples.  Or investigate  $\operatorname {GL}_n(\Bbb k)$, whose commutator is a proper subgroup, $\operatorname {SL}_n(\Bbb k)$, in most cases ($n\neq2$ or $\Bbb k$ not the field consisting of $2$ elements)  See [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup#Examples).)

Or, an index $2$ subgroup is always normal (and, of course,  the quotient abelian).